# If $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=1,\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=2,\int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x)dx=3$,then the number of roots of $f(x)=0$ in $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=1$, $\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=2$, $\int_{0}^{1}x^2f(x)dx=3$, then the number of roots of $f(x)=0$ in $(0,1)$ is:

1. exactly one;
2. atleast one;
3. atmost one;
4. $zero.

---

$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-2x+x^2)f(x)dx=1-4+3=0$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}(x-1)^2f(x)dx=0$$

In the interval $(0,1)$, $(x-1)^2$ is positive. But then I am stuck, how to proceed further.

Comment: Use the mean value theorem for integrals to get $(c - 1)^2 f(c) = 0$ for some $c\in (0,1)$. Then $f(c) = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, the mean value theorem for integrals shows that $f$ has at least one root. However, $f$ may have more than one root. There is a quadratic polynomial that satisfies all the conditions of the problem and has two roots in $(0,1)$, namely, $p(x) = 210x^2 - 192x + 27$.